# Export the types of variables in a SAS dataset

Tags: sas

Is there any easy way to capture and export the type of each variable in a SAS dataset? I'm exporting a dataset to CSV format to read into R, and the `read.table` procedure in the latter can work more efficiently if it also knows the data type of each variable.

Comment: if you have access to IML there are new routines to save SAS data sets into R data frames.  See here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/63541/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_r_sect006.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROC CONTENTS has an OUT= option to ouput a dataset with variable attributes. type=1 is numeric and type=2 is character. HTH.

```
   proc contents data=sashelp.class out=vars;
   run;

   proc print data=vars noobs;
     var varnum name type length;
   run;
   /* on lst
   VARNUM    NAME      TYPE    LENGTH

      3      Age         1        8
      4      Height      1        8
      1      Name        2        8
      2      Sex         2        1
      5      Weight      1        8
   */
```

Comment: Where can I find the map of TYPE?