# Case when to transform string to int if is is not already an int

Tags: sql, teradata, case-when

So, I have the problem that I have a Teradata SQL Code which is quite flexible through macro variables, so the INPUT can be different kinds of Tables. In those
Tables there is alwasy the information s_id, but sometimes the s_id is a string and sometime a int. So I want to transform the strings to an int and if it is already an int then it should just copy the value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT &i as F_ID,    
/*In different Tables the Sid can appear as an string or integer. This CASE WHEN transforms a string into a Integer in case of a not numeric ID*/
CASE WHEN TYPE(data.&columnSId.) not like '%CHAR%' and to_number(data.&columnSId.) is NULL
THEN data.&columnSId. 
WHEN TYPE(data.&columnSId.) like '%CHAR%'                       
THEN CAST(to_number(data.&columnSId.) as FLOAT) 
ELSE 0 
END as s_id,
FROM database.table
```

However somehow in cases when the s_id is already an int it nevertheless tries to use the function to_number which will fail and end in this error:

> Teradata execute: Function 'to_number' called with an invalid number
>   or type of parameters.

Do you know how I can prevent this error? Why it even look at the other case when the first one is already true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *parse time error*, trying to apply To_Number on a numeric value. I don't think you can do what you want without Dynamic SQL.

But this returns a similar result by casting a numeric value to a string first:

```
Coalesce(Cast(To_Number(Trim(data.&columnSId.)) AS INT), 0)
```

Of course it's not very efficient for larger tables.

Comment: Yes, that worked, would it perform better when i generate the sql dynamically on the basis of SAS macros?  So the SAS macro checks first the type of the value and generate then the sql code?

Comment: I just wanted to update, when you use SAS then you can use this solution to program is dynamically --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496159/export-the-types-of-variables-in-a-sas-dataset to get the type of a column.